# Why does an attribute being created through an object descriptor need to have a different value from its original name

Tags: python, descriptor

I have this descriptor class that I wrote that gives me this error when I try to use it in a different class:
`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

```
class x:
    def __init__(...):
        ...

    def __set_name__(self, _, name):
        self.internal_name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, _):
        if instance is None:
            return
        else:
            return getattr(instance, self.internal_name)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if instance is None:
            return
        else:
            setattr(instance, self.internal_name, value)
```

I found that by changing my `__set_name__` method to this I no longer get this issue:

```
def __set_name__(self, _, name):
    self.internal_name = f'_{name}'
```

But I am unsure as to why this is the case. Could you help explain why I need to make sure the name is different from the value I get back from `__set_name__`

Comment: alternatively, for more "descriptive" descriptors you can use `property`s protocols (with and without decorators, see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#pure-python-equivalents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're calling:

```
getattr(instance, self.internal_name)
```

with `self.internal_name` having the same value as the name of the descriptor instance being accessed, so `getattr` invokes another call to `__get__` of the same descriptor instance with the same instance, which again calls `getattr(instance, self.internal_name)`, resulting in infinite recursion. The same situation applies to your call to `setattr`.

By naming `self.internal_name` differently from the name of the descriptor instance, `getattr(instance, self.internal_name)` no longer refers to the descriptor instance for a value and would properly fallback to looking up the the attribute name in the members dict of the instance and the types in the MRO.